# HOW TO install phpmyadmin on debian by ansible?

Tags: phpmyadmin, installation, debian, ansible

On a Debian 7.3 I have installed nginx, mysql, php-fpm by ansible playbook.

In normal, when installing PHPMyAdmin by

```
aptitiude install phpmyadmin
```

It take database password, and do some configurations.

Now for creating a play to install and configuring PHPMyAdmin by ansible what should i do?

### UPDATE

I have wrote a play for installing phpmyadmin. In installation process the it need database username, password and an account for itself. So after searching i found, There is a module in ansible named `debconf` that it can handle some questions for that installations processes. like so:

```
tasks:
- name: debconf for pma
 debconf: name=phpmyadmin question='phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install' value='true' vtype='boolean'

- name: debconf for pma
 debconf: name=phpmyadmin question='phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm' value='{{mysql_root_pass}}' vtype='password'

- name: debconf for pma
 debconf: name=phpmyadmin question='phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass' value='{{mysql_root_pass}}' vtype='password'

- name: debconf for pma
 debconf: name=phpmyadmin question='phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass' value='{{mysql_root_pass}}' vtype='password'

- name: debconf for pma
 debconf: name=phpmyadmin question='phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver' value='' vtype='multiselect'

- name: install pma
 apt: pkg=phpmyadmin state=present

- name: configure site
 file: path=/var/www/pma src=/usr/share/phpmyadmin state=link
```

Now I want to know more about it? About installation and configuration process,?

Comment: Yes i did so. I create a play for installing phpmyadmin but need to know how to configure it by ansible?

Comment: Your question is very vague but you would need to search ansible-galaxy or github for roles for mysql,apache and php. then you would install phpmyadmin with ansible apt module.
Give it a try and ask more focused question

Comment: @DomaNitro, Question updated....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks everybody. I found the problem. a part of my problem was on Mysql installation playbook and some was on above play. All are Like so:

### MySQL

```
tasks:
- name: installing MySQL server on server
  apt: pkg={{item}} update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=86400 state=present
  with_items:
  - python-mysqldb
  - mysql-server

- name: Start mysql service
  service: name=mysql state=started

- name: configuring root user pass and priveliges
  mysql_user: name=root host={{ item }} password={{ mysql_root_pass }} priv=*.*:ALL,GRANT
  with_items:
  - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  - 127.0.0.1
  - ::1
  - localhost

- name: copy root configurations file
  template: src=my.cnf dest=/root/.my.cnf owner=root mode=0600
```

And for

### PHPMyAdmin

```
tasks:
- name: debconf for pma
  debconf: name=phpmyadmin question='phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install' value='true' vtype='boolean'

- name: debconf for pma
  debconf: name=phpmyadmin question='phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm' value='{{mysql_root_pass}}' vtype='password'

- name: debconf for pma
  debconf: name=phpmyadmin question='phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass' value='{{mysql_root_pass}}' vtype='password'

- name: debconf for pma
  debconf: name=phpmyadmin question='phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass' value='{{mysql_root_pass}}' vtype='password'

- name: debconf for pma
  debconf: name=phpmyadmin question='phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver' value='' vtype='multiselect'

- name: install pma
  apt: pkg=phpmyadmin state=present

- name: configure site
  file: path=/var/www/phpmyadmin src=/usr/share/phpmyadmin state=link
```

Comment: Does your playbook is really idempotent ?

Comment: @Zulu, Till now there is no any problem on it.